# How to correctly keep track of variables when iterating object of objects loop that has inner asynchronous code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, base64

I have a Node/Express server that has a GET route from which I need to send back to the client a response that consists of an indexed array of objects where each object has a property 'url' that will get a base64 encoded image using a node library called `base64-img`.

I start with an object of objects and each object has a property 'url' that is a string with a URL address to an image. With `lodash` I am looping through the object of objects - each loop iteration calls `base64Img.requestBase64` that takes the current iteration's `object.url` property and converts the target image at that URL to `base64` encoding. After all objects have been iterated through, I want to send to the client a response that is an INDEXED array (0, 1, 2, etc) of the objects.

I simply do NOT know how to make sure the response is sent only once when the loop is done and all images are encoded correctly because of the asynchronous flow. The following code doesn't work because sometimes I have the full array and sometimes not, but the client always receives and array that contains a single object and not the full array containing all objects. Please help.

```
    /*

userProfileImages = {
    {url: 'http://www.someurl.com/blah1'},
    {url: 'http://www.someurl.com/blah2'},
    {url: 'http://www.someurl.com/blah3'},
    {url: 'http://www.someurl.com/blah4'}
}

 */

let completeRequests = 0;
let arrayOfUserProfileImages = [];
_.map(userProfileImages, (userProfileImage, key) => {

completeRequests++;

let tmpCount = completeRequests;
let tmpUserProfileImage = userProfileImage;

// loop through each of the userProfileImages,
// get each image by the url in userProfileImage
base64Img.requestBase64(
    tmpUserProfileImage.url,
    function(error, messageRes, body) {

        // if image conversion successful, proceed
        if (!error) {

            // get the base64 code and set it as the new
            // value of the userProfileImage url property
            tmpUserProfileImage.url = body;

            // push the object into the array
            arrayOfUserProfileImages.push(tmpUserProfileImage);
            console.log('ARRAY LENGTH:', arrayOfUserProfileImages.length);
            console.log(arrayOfUserProfileImages);

            // if number of request matches the total number
            // of requests to complete, we are done, return
            // the appropriate json response
            if (tmpCount === numberOfRequestsToMake) {
                console.log(arrayOfUserProfileImages);
                return res.json({ userProfileImages: arrayOfUserProfileImages });
            }

        // else return json error
        } else {
            return res.json({error: error});
        }

    } // end callback

); // end base64Img

}); // end _.map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop/array is a lot easier to reason with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

First convert the `requestBase64` callback into a Promise. You can normally use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_defaultoptions) if the callback function signature is `(error, result)` but in this case the 3 arguments in the signature requires manual setup.

```
function requestBase64(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    base64Img.requestBase64(url, (error, messageRes, body) => {
      if (error) return reject(error)
      resolve(body)
    })
  })
}
```

Then create an array of promises, each will request the url, wait for the response, and create an object with the response body as the url.

```
let p = _.map(userProfileImages, async (userProfileImage, key) => {
  let body = await requestBase64(userProfileImage.url)
  let base64userProfileImage = _.cloneDeep(userProfileImage)
  return _.merge(base64userProfileImage, { url: body })
})
```

Then wait for all the promises in the array to resolve before sending the response.

```
try {
  let userProfileImages = await Promise.all(p)
  return res.json({ userProfileImages: userProfileImages })
} catch (error){
  return res.json({ error: error })
}
```

Note that [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) requirea [Node.js 7.6+](https://v8project.blogspot.fr/2016/10/v8-release-55.html) or [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). The plain Promise code using `.then()` is not vastly different.

Also note that you must be inside an `async` function to use `await`. Whatever the function is that houses all this code, I assume it's an express route handler, will also need to be tagged as `async`.

Comment: Thank you so much this solved all my issues. Do you have any resources you recommend or online classes (udemy) that explains these async/await/Promise concepts in detail? I'm really knew to all of this and having a difficult time grasping this. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any handy. You probably need something that explains how asynchronous functions work first so you get the general concepts, then convert that to promises, then async/await is a simple jump.

Comment: Here's a [good overview of each](https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/), but it's not much of an intro/tutorial.